# как получить id записи из pivot table после attach ? Laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Таблица `user_test`:

```sql
 id user_id test_id quantity 
  1  1       3       30
  2  1       3       50 
  3  1       3       180
```

Каждый раз вставляется в данном случае по 1 записи
пример последней записи:

```php
$user->tests()->attach(3, array('quantity' => 180);
```

так вот можно как получить id этой последней записи?
типа

```php
$idPivot = $user->tests()->attach(3, array('quantity' => 180);
```

чтобы потом поменять это число с 180 на любое не трогая при этом другие ?

Типа так:

```php
$affected = DB::table('user_test')
              ->where('id', 3)
              ->update(['quantity' => 35]);
```

Comment: [Get the ID of the last attached model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562121/get-the-id-of-the-last-attached-model), или же используйте метод [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)